# How to publish an array of 3D points for visualization in RVIZ? [Solved]

Tags: ros, c++, rviz, markerarray, visualization-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I did all the basic tutorials of visualization_msgs for publishing points as different shaped markers.
is it possible for anyone to let me know how to publish an array of points so that I can see them in rviz in real time.

I have an array of 20 points in 3D and I want to publish them as visualization_msgs/markerArray. But I have no idea how to do that.

It will be a great help if anyone can provide a snippet in c++ for this purpose.

Thanks,
Prasanna.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231186/how-to-publish-an-array-of-3d-points-for-visualization-in-rviz?-%5Bsolved%5D/) by [PKumars](https://answers.ros.org/users/25000/pkumars/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2016-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use a simple Marker (no Markerarray!) and use the Points-Type (http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Points_.28POINTS.3D8.29). The Marker (http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/Marker.html) has a points member that can be used to pass a list of points to RVIZ. If you want to have a nicer output you could also use the SPHERE_LIST although all spheres will have the same color.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PKumars](https://answers.ros.org/users/25000/pkumars/) on 2016-04-06**:
Thanks for your quick reply. what if the points are not fixed and are changing and then I have just an array. I know only that it is of 3d type and I don'n want to change the points manually? the points are also not linear in spacing. I mean to say that the points of my array can be any where.

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-04-06**:
You can just republish your points after their position changed. How often do you want to update the position in RVIZ?

**Comment by [PKumars](https://answers.ros.org/users/25000/pkumars/) on 2016-04-06**:
I want to publish all the points at once. is it possible? and then delete in next iteration.

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-04-06**:
Yes. You send one marker that contains your 20 points. If you publish again (with the same namespace and id), the old points are replaced by the new ones.

**Comment by [PKumars](https://answers.ros.org/users/25000/pkumars/) on 2016-04-06**:
I'm sorry But I can't figure out how to do that. I followed http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Points%20and%20Lines this tutorial and used only points and not lines. Still now I'm unable to solve this problem.

**Comment by [PKumars](https://answers.ros.org/users/25000/pkumars/) on 2016-04-07**:
Thanks for your kind and detailed suggestion. I solved the problem and I'm posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is example C++ marker array code in [ros-visualization/rviz//src/test/marker_test.cpp](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/blob/kinetic-devel/src/test/marker_test.cpp)

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-04-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PKumars](https://answers.ros.org/users/25000/pkumars/) on 2016-04-06**:
Hi Lucas,
Thanks for your answer but is it so long and complicated? I need your explanation about which part of your code I nedd to use if I want to publish 20 points at once and want to see them in Rviz.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-04-06**:
Skip down to the part which uses `visualization_msgs::Marker::POINTS`, the file is very long because it is testing all of the marker types.

**Comment by [PKumars](https://answers.ros.org/users/25000/pkumars/) on 2016-04-07**:
Thanks Lucas for your kind help. I solved that and I'm posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is the solution that I wanted. both of the above answers helped me in getting a beautiful output.

I'm posting the solution now.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <visualization_msgs/Marker.h>
#include <cmath>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "spheres");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Publisher marker_pub = n.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker>("ball_trajectory", 10);

  ros::Rate r(30);

  float f = 0.0;
  while (ros::ok())
  {

    visualization_msgs::Marker sphere_list;
    sphere_list.header.frame_id= "/my_frame";
    sphere_list.header.stamp= ros::Time::now();
    sphere_list.ns= "spheres";
    sphere_list.action= visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD;
    sphere_list.pose.orientation.w= 1.0;

    sphere_list.id = 0;

    sphere_list.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::SPHERE_LIST;


    // POINTS markers use x and y scale for width/height respectively
    sphere_list.scale.x = 0.1;
    sphere_list.scale.y = 0.1;
    sphere_list.scale.z = 0.1;

    // Points are green
    sphere_list.color.r = 1.0f;
    sphere_list.color.a = 1.0;


    // Create the vertices for the points and lines
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
    {
      float y = sin(f + i / 100.0f * 2 * M_PI);
      float z = cos(f + i / 100.0f * 2 * M_PI);

      geometry_msgs::Point p;
      p.x = (int32_t)i*0.2;
      p.y = y;
      p.z = z;

      sphere_list.points.push_back(p);

    }
    marker_pub.publish(sphere_list);

    r.sleep();

    f += 0.04;
  }
}
```

if there is any mistake or anyone has got any doubt regarding this code then please let me know. I will be happy to help and correct my mistakes.

EDIT
Sorry I forgot to mention other details.

put this in CMakelists.txt
add_executable(ball_trajectory src/ball_trajectory.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ball_trajectory ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

where ball_trajectory is the .cpp file

then catkin_make

then in RVIZ do this.

1. set Fixed Frame to           my_frame. (Note:- if there is no option my_frame then edit yourself)
2. Add ->options ->Marker
3. set Marker Topic to          ball_trajectory. (here visualization msg topic is ball_trajectory)

Note:- Do not get confused with .cpp file name and published topic name, can be changed easily and independent of each other.

Regards,
Prasanna

---

Originally posted by [PKumars](https://answers.ros.org/users/25000/pkumars/) with karma: 92 on 2016-04-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1